# Import flat file into SQL Server 2005 with Import/Export wizard gives product level error

Tags: sql-server, ssis, data-import

I am using SQL Server Management Studio Enterprise 2005.

I am trying to import a text file with pipe delimited data into my SQLserver table. 
However when the process of importing, the system gave me this error log:

Operation stopped...

- Initializing Data Flow Task (Success)
- Initializing Connections (Success)
- Setting SQL Command (Success)
- Setting Source Connection (Success)
- Setting Destination Connection (Success)
- Validating (Error)
  Messages
  Error 0xc00470fe: Data Flow Task: The product level is insufficient for component "Source - userrolelist_TXT" (1).
  (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc00470fe: Data Flow Task: The product level is insufficient for component "Data Conversion 1" (95).
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

- Prepare for Execute (Stopped)
- Pre-execute (Stopped)
- Executing (Success)
- Copying to [SOD].[dbo].[userrolelist] (Stopped)
- Post-execute (Stopped)
- Cleanup (Stopped)

I have read that I would need to install SP2 because this is a bug. Anyone know how can I solve this and are there any other alternative I can use to import a pipe delimited data file into my tables?

Comment: So have you installed the latest servicepack for SQL 2005 (SP4) or not?

Comment: @MitchWheat, SSMS's Import/Export wizard generates and runs an SSIS package behind the scenes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Services required for SSIS on your SQL Server installation might not have been installed such as ervice, dtexec, and dtexecui.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/289d0bbb-1d06-4856-9c66-8d3e540d7be9/

Answer (score 0):

> are there any other alternative I can use to import a pipe delimited
>   data file into my tables?

I believe Kip has hit the nail on the head with the Integration Services Service not being installed.

If this is a straight import of data, it's hard to beat [bcp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx) or [BULK INSERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188365.aspx).